# react js JSX not rendering as expected

Tags: reactjs, jsx

conditional rendering not working.

```
<Paper elevation={1} className={classes.childPaper}>
                    Status : {status === 'SUCCESS' && 
                        <b style={{ marginLeft: '43px', fontSize: '14px', color: 'green' }}>Completed </b> }
                    {status === 'FAILED' &&
                        <b style={{ marginLeft: '43px', fontSize: '14px', color: 'red' }}>Failed</b>}
                    {status === 'Processing' &&
                        <b style={{ marginLeft: '43px', fontSize: '14px', color: 'gold' }}>Processing</b>}
                    {status !== 'SUCCESS' && status !== 'FAILED' && status !== 'Processing' && <b style={{ marginLeft: '43px', fontSize: '14px' }}>
                        {{comments} !== ''? {status} [{comments}] : {status}} </b>}
                </Paper>
```

comments and status have been destructured from props

i want it to display status: Completed [Dummy comment] if comments is not an empty string and only status: Completed if comments is an empty string.

Comment: if you console log out `status` what does it give? also when saying `rendering not working.` - what do you mean? what results you getting? whats wrong? doe sit work at first but then dosent work when `status` changes? we need more info